# Emacs insert-buffer ignores line breaks?

Tags: emacs

I'm having trouble inserting a buffer in Emacs.  Say I have the following two files:

file1.txt

```
1st line
```

file2.txt

```
2nd line
3rd line
```

If I open file1.txt in Emacs and then insert file2.txt with `C-x C-i`, the result is

```
1st line
2nd line 3rd line
```

and not

```
1st line
2nd line
3rd line
```

Am I missing something here?  I'm running GNU Emacs 23.2.1 on Windows 7.  Both files are in the default utf-8-dos encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.  I have `longlines-mode` enabled for text files.  If I disable it, or better yet switch to `visual-line-mode`, the file is inserted as expected.